# Clarity about transitions/animations in Ionic

Tags: animation, ionic-framework, transition

I really hope an Ionic ninja reads this. ;)

In both, [Android Material Design (by specification)](https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/tabs.html#tabs-specs) and in iOS (by UX design trends) **Tabbed Views should be swipe'able and have a sliding transition animation**.

I created an Ionic app (latest version) from the Starter "Tabs".

```
$ ionic start myApp tabs
```

To give it a more "native" look and feel, I added swiping gestures to each Tab by adding this to each controller:

```
.controller('TabOneCtrl', function($scope, $ionicTabsDelegate) {

    $scope.goForward = function () {
        var selected = $ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex();
        if (selected != -1) {
            $ionicTabsDelegate.select(selected + 1);
        }
    }

    $scope.goBack = function () {
        var selected = $ionicTabsDelegate.selectedIndex();
        if (selected != -1 && selected != 0) {
            $ionicTabsDelegate.select(selected - 1);
        }
    }

})
```

and adding this to every view:

```
<ion-content class="padding" on-swipe-right="goBack()" on-swipe-left="goForward()">
```

**So far, so good - I can swipe between the 3 tabs and their views, but it doesn't feel "native" (at least on Android), because the views just pop up and don't slide in...** So I spent the last 6 hrs googling here, on the Ionic Forums, GitHub and elsewhere - But instead of clarity I am only more confused by the hour. So far I have dug up the following contradicting information:

- add `animation="slide-left-right"` to `ion-nav-view`
- add `animate='slide-left-right"` to `ion-nav-view`
- add `class='slide-left-right"` to `ion-nav-view`
- the animation directive has been **removed from Ionic**
- the animation directive should be in the `<a>` tag
- don't touch it. Ionic will take care of it itself.

and half a dozen other confusing and contradicting information - none of which is working for me. (Strangely enough though `nav-direction="back"` in an `<a>` tag produces the correct animation when navigating back.)

Could anyone from the Ionic "cracks" shine some light on this issue and clarify what **the best practice** is for adding page/view transition animations to Ionic apps. I think a lot of newbies would greatly appreciate this (furthermost me myself).

Comment: It's a shame no one replied to this yet. I'm having the same problem.

Comment: You can setup Native-transition-plugin for what you are searching. I have been same through problem but did not found any solution.